# The new version of admob not pay via Paypal

Tags: paypal, admob, payment

I just got an email that says "Switch to the new version of AdMob today"
With various links. [This seems like the main one](https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/3077517?hl=it&utm_source=admobupgrade&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=admob%20upgrade).
Then there was also a notification in the old page admob
We launched a new version of AdMob with the button "Upgrade"

I clicked the button and I followed several steps to register. In practice, I believe that I signed up to this new site as if it were a separate service fortunately without affecting the old site Admob (There is a function that is used to import the old data that I have not clicked) I checked contains all the data earlier, even though I checked out the advertising in applications and is still served. In a few hours will check also if the revenues, impressions, etc. are updated.

Do you have news about this?
Is there a deadline for forced into to this new site?
It will be mandatory to switch to this new site?

Is there any of you that is in my same situation? What are your intentions? Open a bank account or switch to another company that makes payments with PayPal?

It might be useful to make a petition calling for Paypal as a payment method?

Thank you for your answers and advice

Comment: Please keep PayPal as payment method. I clicked upgrade as well, but not Import. I hope I can keep on using the old admob as long as possible (as long as Paypal is not supported in the new admob).

Comment: I live in Malaysia where new admob is not available for upgrade yet but i started to see my earning dropped more than 50% this month. This is so unfair.

Comment: Paypal is good but Google make our life more difficult with less option :(

Answer (score 5):

It seems that paypal is not supported from now on...

> "New payment options: Forms of payment will no longer include PayPal and Wire".

https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/2772061?hl=en